# Is schema Id sent every time as a part of record while publishing message from producer or only for newly registered schemas?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I'm using confluent Schema Registry
I have registered multiple schemas under the same subject.

If I try to publish a record, is schema Id is sent as a part of the record (even if from cache) or is it just at the time of registering a new version of schema to the schema registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every record has a schema ID. That way, a consumer can read any one message and deserialize the data

https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/serializer-formatter.html#wire-format

Comment: How does the producer decide which id to send?
Suppose we have 7 versions of schema available under same subject,
Does it get's mapped with the incoming message schema and decide on the version, or it just checks for compatibility with the latest one and sends the latest Id?

Comment: Each schema is posted to the registry. The registry computes an MD5 hash for uniqueness and returns the ID. The client then stores the schema by the MD5 hash and sends the record with the ID. As mentioned before, feel free to open the source code set breakpoints and debug the serializer flow